# Rectangle.intersection(Rectangle) returning a Rectangle with negative width and height

Tags: java, awt, rectangles

Does anyone know the circumstances in which this happens or should happen a cursory glance at the documentation is not helpful.

Comment: Are you seeing it happen? I don't believe it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only happen in the event the Rectangles do not intersect. For example

```
new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10).intersection(new Rectangle(100, 100, 10, 10))
```

Would have negative width and height.

Comment: please why Rectangles is not intersect

Comment: two 10 by 10 rectangles do not intersect if one is at (0,0) and the other at (100,100)

Comment: originally I was sure that works and  correctly (Java6 in year 2013:-), no idea about yours ...

Comment: I'd have expected a null return if there was no intersection.